# Amazon S3 settings for Development and Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave and Fog to upload images and process them to Amazon S3.

Below is my Fog settings.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'AKIAJ23D1I25B2P2HX6A',
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'WV64nQAd111+ZelqKgffrzvViG0lEeTTnEOonXHkg'#,
    #:region                 => 'us-west-2'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = "<TESTING>"
end
```

Is there a way to have two settings that gets used when the app is in production and development environment so that we dont mess with the files in the product and can delete it in dev one.

Comment: I hope those aren't valid credentials ...

Comment: @FrederickCheung no sir... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use different settings by specifying in the particular environment. I am using this in my project but what I have done is I am using different directories for both. Like in the `production.rb` I am using `project_directory` and in `development.rb` I am using `project_dev_directory`. I have specified the same settings in both the environments. If you need to specify different settings you can do that too. Hope this helps.